# File transferring over TCP java

Tags: java, sockets, file-io, tcp

I am doing the experiment for my own curiosity about transferring any file over the TCP connection between server and client

My project is "Server receives a file" and "Client sends that file"

But seems like something going wrong, The client-end can send the whole file and Server-end also can receive the whole file BUT after receiving at the server-end the file cannot be open it's like something went wrong while reading and sending its chunks

Could you check if I'm doing something wrong

Here's my code for Server side

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class TFServer2 {

private static ServerSocket servSock;
private static int port;

public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException{

    if(args.length < 1){
        port = 1500;
    }else{
        port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    }

    servSock = new ServerSocket(port);
    int i = 1;

    while(true){
        System.out.println("Listening connection...");
        Socket client = servSock.accept();

        System.out.println("Client " + i + "requires connection!");
        ClientHandler ch = new ClientHandler(client);
        ch.setNumber(i++);
        ch.start();
    }
}
}
```

and here's ClientHandler

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.Socket;


public class ClientHandler extends Thread{

private int i;

private Socket client;
private ObjectInputStream sInt;
private String fileName;
private int file_size;
private File file;
private FileOutputStream outStr;
private BufferedOutputStream bos;


public ClientHandler(Socket client) throws IOException{
    this.client = client;

    this.sInt = new ObjectInputStream(this.client.getInputStream());
}

public void setNumber(int i){
    this.i = i;
}

public void run(){

    try {
        System.out.println("Client " + i + ": " + client.getInetAddress() + " connected on port " + client.getPort());

        //get filename
        fileName = (String) sInt.readObject();
        String[] str = fileName.split(".");

        //get file size
        file_size = sInt.readInt();

        //open file
        file = new File("D:\\practice_java_network\\TransferFileServer\\Download\\" + fileName);

        //create file output stream
        outStr = new FileOutputStream(file);

        //create buffered output
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(outStr);

        byte[] buffer = null;
        int total_read_len = 0;

        //receiving file loop
        while( sInt.readBoolean() ){
            buffer = (byte[]) sInt.readObject();
            total_read_len += buffer.length;
            bos.write(buffer);

            System.out.println("Receive: " + (float)total_read_len/file_size*100 + "%");
        }

        //close all connection
        bos.close();
        outStr.close();
        sInt.close();
        client.close();

        System.out.println("connection with client " + i + " closed");
        System.out.println("Done receiving file");
        System.out.println("File contained at: " + file.toPath());

        return;
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

and here's code for client side

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class TFClientv2 {

private static Socket socket;
private static int port;
private static String host;
private static String fileName;
private static File file;
private static BufferedInputStream bis;
private static ObjectOutputStream sOut;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    try{
        System.out.println("Args: " + args.length);

        //check arguments
        if(args.length < 1)
            host = "somehost";
        else
            host = args[0];
        System.out.println("Host: " + host);

        if(args.length < 2)
            port = 1500;
        else
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        System.out.println("port: " + port);

        if(args.length < 3){
            System.out.print("File: ");
            fileName = sc.nextLine();
            fileName = insert(fileName, '\\');
        }else{
            fileName = insert(args[2], '\\');
        }
        //done checking arguments


        //test if the file does exist
        file = new File(fileName);
        if(!file.exists()){
            System.out.println("There's no such file!");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        /*
         * create input Stream to read file
         */
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));



        /*
         * connect to host preparing to send the file
         * and create get outputStream
         */
        System.out.println("Opening connection with host: " + host);
        socket = new Socket(host, port);
        System.out.println("Connected to host " + socket.getInetAddress());
        sOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        /*
         * extract only exact file name(not path)
         * and send to server
         */
        String[] str = fileName.split("\\\\");
        sOut.writeObject(str[str.length-1]);
        System.out.println("Preparing file \"" + str[str.length-1] + "\" to be sent");


        /*
         * these variables necessary to be used
         * for sending file
         */
        int file_len = (int) file.length();
        int buff_size = 1024;
        int bytesRead = 0;
        int total_read_len = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[buff_size];

        int file_len_2 = file_len;

        //tell server to know size of the file
        sOut.writeInt(file_len);

        //This one copy the file in exact size
        //begin read and send chunks of file in loop
        while( file_len_2 > 0 ){
            if( file_len_2 < buff_size ){
                buffer = new byte[file_len_2];
                bytesRead = bis.read(buffer);
            }else{
                bytesRead = bis.read(buffer);
            }

            file_len_2 -= bytesRead;
            total_read_len += bytesRead;
            sOut.writeBoolean(true);
            sOut.writeObject(buffer);
            System.out.println("Sent: " + (float)total_read_len/file_len*100 + "%");
        }

        //This one copy a little bit bigger
        /*while( (bytesRead = bis.read(buffer)) != -1 ){
            total_read_len += bytesRead;
            sOut.writeBoolean(true);
            sOut.writeObject(buffer);
            System.out.println("Sent: " + (float)total_read_len/file_len*100 + "%");
        }*/

        sOut.writeBoolean(false);

        System.out.println("Done sending file!");

        //close all connection
        bis.close();
        sOut.close();
        socket.close();


    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String insert(String str, char ch){
    StringBuilder strBuff = new StringBuilder(str);
    int c = 0;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < str.length() ; i++){
        if(str.charAt(i) == ch){
            strBuff.insert(i+c, ch);
            c++;
        }
    }

    return strBuff.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: `file cannot be open` What do you mean? With Java or through window interface?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think the OP means that the file was corrupted during the transfer

Comment: the `insert()` is not required. Escaping backslashes only applies to String literals. any other string does not require escaping.

Answer (score -1):

At Client side write    `sOut.flush()`  after each `sOut.write()`operations.

When you write in the `stream` then you need to `flush` the `stream` so that reader can get the data from the `stream`.

Comment: You shouldn't flush after every write, only at the end of the transfer.